# Window Tansparency - set for one window only

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, transparency

I'm running Xubuntu 13.10 and have set inactive windows to be transparent.  However, is there a way to prevent one window/program (i.e. tvtime) from becoming transparent.

[See this screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrzKpGlppKUQ3BkaTBrdFNQeEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to play a little with compiz to get this. Install compizconfig:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it:

```
ccsm
```

And under the Windows Rules section you'll find this rule: "No ARGB visuals". You need there a way to identify your window, either the title, class, etc:

[image]

Comment: That didn't work.  I followed your instructions.  I entered the following in the "No ARGB visuals" field:  (tvtime) & title=tvtime.  I did this by using the + button, choosing Window Title, and entering "tvtime".  See screenshot (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrzKpGlppKUZFBNVTBPUnExT28/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I think it didn't work because tvtime changes the window title each time you change the channel.  So, how do I identify the Window ID or the Window Class.  Something else that might identify this program only.

Comment: I also tried using the following:

class=tvtime
-and-
name=TVWindow

Neither option worked.

Comment: I can't help you with that, you'll have to find something that exactly identifies that only window. The command xwininfo may help you a little.